# How to evaluate $\lim_{x \to1}\frac{x- \ln x-1}{(x-1)^2}$ without L'Hopital?

Tags: limits-without-lhopital

I will be thankful if somebody help me to solve this limit without L'Hospital's rule

$$\lim \limits_{x \to1}\frac{x- \ln x-1}{(x-1)^2}$$

Comment: Is allowed to use derivatives ?

Answer (score 3):

**HINT:**

$$\log(x)=(x-1)-\frac12 (x-1)^2+O(x-1)^3$$

---

Comment: Not Good, it uses derivatives, why would it be more helpful than lhospitall?

Comment: @frusciante14 Why do you believe that use of a Taylor expansion is equivalent to LHR?

Comment: I suppose that he does not want to use Lhospitall because he does not want to use derivatives.

Comment: @frusciante14 Do you know of a way forward that does not rely on calculus?

Answer (score 1):

If we use the change $u=x-1$,

then the limit becomes

$$\lim_{u\to 0}\frac{u-ln(1+u)}{u^2}$$

$$=\lim_{u\to 0}\frac{u-u+\frac{1}{2u^2}(1+\epsilon(u))}{u^2}$$

$$=\frac12.$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $x=1+h.$ Then the expression equals

$$\tag 1 \frac{h - \ln (1+h)}{h^2} = \frac{1}{h^2}\int_1^{1+h}(1-1/t)\, dt.$$

Let $t= 1+s$ to see $(1)$ equals

$$\tag 2 \frac{1}{h^2}\int_0^{h}s/(1+s)\, ds.$$

Suppose $h>0.$ For small $s>0, 1-s < 1/(1+s) < 1-s +s^2,$ which gives $s-s^2 <s/(1+s) < s-s^2 + s^3.$ Thus $(2)$ is bounded below by $(h^2/2 -h^3/3)/h^2$ and bounded above by $(h^2/2 -h^3/3+h^4/4)/h^2.$ Both bounding expressions $\to 1/2$ as $h\to 0^+.$ Hence so does $(1).$ The argument is similar if $h\to 0^-.$

So, a longer proof, but we use no Taylor and no L'Hopital.